# How to instruct Jackson ObjectMapper to not convert number field value into a String property?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have the following JSON sample:

```
{
    "channel": "VTEX",
    "data": "{}",
    "refId": 143433.344,
    "description": "teste",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}
```

That should map to the following class:

```
public class AddConfigInput {
    public String channel;
    public String data;
    public String refId;
    public String description;
    public String[] tags;

    public AddConfigInput() {
    }
}
```

Using a code like bellow:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS);
String json = STRING_CONTAINING_THE_PREVIOUS_INFORMED_JSON;
AddConfigInput obj = mapper.readValue(json, AddConfigInput.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj));
```

That produces as output:

```
{"channel":"VTEX","data":"{}","refId":"143433.344","description":"teste","tags":["tag1","tag2"]}
```

Please note that the field **refId** is of type **String** and I want to avoid this kind of automatic conversion from Numbers to String properties. Instead I want to Jackson throws an error about the type mismatch. How can I do that?

Comment: So you want Jackson to deserialize and deserialize a `String` field as a Double?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Jackson is converting 143433.344 (number in JSON)  to the String property refId "143433.344" in the Java class, but I want a type mismatch error be thrown by Jackson.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop Jackson reading numbers as String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404706/stop-jackson-reading-numbers-as-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS);` works for the reverse case, that is, parsing fails when deserializing `String` value to numeric field.

Providing custom deserializer for the `refId` field seems to resolve this issue.

```java
public class AddConfigInput {
    public String channel;
    public String data;

    //@JsonDeserialize(using = ForceStringDeserializer.class)
    public String refId;
    public String description;
    public String[] tags;

    public AddConfigInput() {
    }
}
```

```
public class ForceStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(
            JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) 
            throws IOException 
    {
        if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            deserializationContext.reportWrongTokenException(
                    String.class, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING, 
                    "Attempted to parse token %s to string",
                    jsonParser.getCurrentToken());
        }
        return jsonParser.getValueAsString();
    }
}
```

**Update**
This custom deserializer may be registered within the `ObjectMapper` and override default behaviour:

```java
public class ForcedStringParserModule extends SimpleModule {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ForcedStringParserModule() {
        this.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {

            @Override
            public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(
                    DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc,
                    JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) 
            {
                if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass())) {
                    return new ForceStringDeserializer();
                }
                return deserializer;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then this module can be registered with `ObjectMapper`:

```
mapper.registerModule(new ForcedStringParserModule ());
```

After modifying slightly the input JSON (using boolean for `data` field which must be String), the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
Unexpected token (VALUE_FALSE), expected VALUE_STRING: 
Attempted to parse token VALUE_FALSE to string
 at [Source: (String)"{
    "channel": "VTEX",
    "data": false,
    "refId": "143433.344",
    "description": "teste",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}"; line: 3, column: 13]
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works for you.

I have added a custom deserializer for attribute refId, there I am checking the type and in case there is a data type mismatch throwing Exception.

Custom deserializer used for force datatype check.

KeepStringDeserializer.java

```
package oct2020.json;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class KeepStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
            DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            throw deserializationContext.wrongTokenException(jsonParser,
                    String.class, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING,
                    "Expected value is string but other datatype found.");
        }
        return jsonParser.getValueAsString();
    }
}
```

AddConfigInput.java

For refId attribute using custom deserializer.

```
package oct2020.json;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

public class AddConfigInput {
    public String channel;
    public String data;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = KeepStringDeserializer.class)
    public String refId;
    public String description;
    public String[] tags;

    public AddConfigInput() {
    }
}
```

TestClient.java

```
package oct2020.json;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\n    \"channel\": \"VTEX\",\n    \"data\": \"{}\",\n    \"refId\": 143433.344,\n    \"description\": \"teste\",\n    \"tags\": [\"tag1\", \"tag2\"]\n}\"";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS);
        AddConfigInput obj = mapper.readValue(json, AddConfigInput.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj));
    }
}
```

Output:

Case1: data mismatch

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT), Expected value is string but other datatype found.
 at [Source: (String)"{
    "channel": "VTEX",
    "data": "{}",
    "refId": 143433.344,
    "description": "teste",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}""; line: 4, column: 14] (through reference chain: oct2020.json.AddConfigInput["refId"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
```

Case2: Correct data

Input:

```
String json = "{\n    \"channel\": \"VTEX\",\n    \"data\": \"{}\",\n    \"refId\": \"143433.344\",\n    \"description\": \"teste\",\n    \"tags\": [\"tag1\", \"tag2\"]\n}\"";
```

Output:

```
{"channel":"VTEX","data":"{}","refId":"143433.344","description":"teste","tags":["tag1","tag2"]}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! But, I want this validation be the default one for every String field in my app. Is there some way to make the KeepStringDeserializer the default one for String fields?

Comment: @tonyfarney, it is possible to [register a module with `ObjectMapper` to override default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188068/13279831), however it affects parsing of all Strings.