# Read empty string from JSON to empty List<...>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a List field in my POJO. List so:

```
public class Student {
    private List<String> courseNames;
    ...
}
```

When the in-coming JSON (from 3rd-party) contains an array (like the following), it is not an issue.

```
{
    "courseNames": ["abc", "xyz"]
}
```

But the 3rd party app sometimes sends an empty array. Like so:

```
{
    "courseNames": ""
}
```

In this case, I like to have my `courseNames` field populated as an empty list.

Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64187002/how-to-instruct-jackson-objectmapper-to-not-convert-number-field-value-into-a-st), I figured implementing a custom JsonDeserializer is one way to achieve this.

So I partially implemented it:

```
public class StringToEmptyListJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        if(jsonParser.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return // What to do here?
    }
}
```

Are there any suggestions on how to delegate to the default List<...> JsonDeserializer? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: @dariosicily, This works. Thank you. If you post it as an answer, I am happy to accept it.

Comment: Glad to have helped, I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the [`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT) feature to allow JSON empty String value ("") to be bound as `null` for POJOs and other structured values (Maps, Collections). So the value will be converted either to a non empty list or an empty list like below:

```
@Data
public class Student {
    private List<String> courseNames;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
//a non empty courseNames array 
String courseNames = "{\"courseNames\": [\"abc\", \"xyz\"]}";
Student student = mapper.readValue(courseNames, Student.class);
//ok, it prints {"courseNames":["abc","xyz"]}
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(student));
//an empty courseNames array
courseNames = "{\"courseNames\": []}";
student = mapper.readValue(courseNames, Student.class);
//ok, it prints the empty courseNames array
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(student));
```